# Dúvida sobre ponteiro e matriz

Tags: c, ponteiro, matriz

Olá, estava tentando fazer um exercício no qual pediu para imprimir o endereço de cada posição da matriz utilizando ponteiro e estou em dúvida se está correto.
Procurei alguns vídeos no youtube e só achei explicação para matrizes unidimensionais.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    float matrix[3][3];
    float **xmatrix= matrix;

    printf("Endereços de memória\n\n");

    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {

            printf("Membro [%d] [%d]\n\n",i,j);
            printf("%d\n\n\n",xmatrix+j+i);\\aqui fiquei em dúvida em com faria para imprimir os próximos 
                                           \\membros

        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E se estiver certo ,o porque de alguns dos endereços se repetirem.

Desde já agradeço.

Comment: ele está repetindo porque você está somando o endereço + i + j, perceba por exemplo nos casos [0][1] e [1][0] são iguais pq x+1+0 = x+0+1 , ao meu ver a forma mais facil de se pegar os endereços do ponteiro seria com um & na matrix, ex: &matrix[0][1]

Comment: Se quiser utilizar da forma como está em seu programa a fórmula correta é: `xmatrix+j+(2*i)` onde este 2 é o tamanho da linha de sua matriz.

Answer (score 2):

Em `C`, a melhor maneira de se exibir o endereço de um ponteiro é usando o especificador de conversão `%p` na string de formatação do `printf()`.

Para se obter o endereço de uma variável usa-se o operador `&`, veja só como seu programa ficaria:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i, j;
    float matrix[3][3];

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        for(j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            printf("%d,%d = %p\n", i, j, &matrix[i][j]);

    return 0;
}
```

Possível saída:

```
0,0 = 0x7ffd005baad0
0,1 = 0x7ffd005baad4
0,2 = 0x7ffd005baad8
1,0 = 0x7ffd005baadc
1,1 = 0x7ffd005baae0
1,2 = 0x7ffd005baae4
2,0 = 0x7ffd005baae8
2,1 = 0x7ffd005baaec
2,2 = 0x7ffd005baaf0
```